# Use one javascript script to dynamically modify another script

Tags: javascript, html

Yo!

I have an arbitrary javascript file, let's call it `localScript`, and just say it looks something like this:

```
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript">
    function () {
        var blue = 'blue';
        var person = {
           firstName:"John",
           lastName:"Doe",
           age:50,
           eyeColor:"brown"
        };
        var bluePerson = function () {
           person[color] = blue;
        };
    }
</script>
```

I want to be able to use another `externalScript` to dynamically change the contents of this `localScript`. For this simple example, let's just say I want to update some of the values in `localScript`, like—maybe change `age` of the `person` object to 75. (Obviously, there's very simple ways to do this, but for my use case it's imperative that I use another `externalScript` to generate the contents of this `localScript`).

It would be easy if there was something like `.innerHtml` which I could use in the `externalScript` which would allow me to select an `element` and then replace the 'innerHtml' contents. The `localScript`, though, obviously isn't composed of elements.

As far as I know, when using a script to modify another script, there aren't any 'easy' ways to reference variables/objects/items in the script.

Things I've considered are `indexOf()`, `search()`, and `match()`, which I could use in  `externalScript` to find strings inside `localScript` and then replace the values. I feel though as these could be performance no-no's, especially if the script grows.

Are there any easy ways to do this—with an emphasis on performance? I feel like there must be some easy way to reference one of the items in the script, though, I suppose a script is all one large string.. and maybe there is no simple way.

BTW—I'm using AngularJS, if there are any built in methods—though I think this is mostly just a javascript thing.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: All of what you have shown is in the global window space. So it can be accessed from anywhere. So therefore is hard to see where you have a problem unless you have oversimplified the example

Comment: OK..that change made it checkmate

Comment: I feel like we might need more context on this problem. What is preventing you from passing in a person object? or passing in the 'Blue' variable? Are you not allowed to modify the external script?

Comment: In this specific context, the DOM loads, the ```localScript``` executes and then I prefer to change some values and then have it re-execute, via ```eval()```.

Comment: WHat is the actual use case of existing script and what are you trying to overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change the variables. Refer following steps

1. Include external script just below the script you have written.
2. Access the variables in the external script as if they are locally declared.

The variables you have created in above script are available in global scope and hence should be accessible from everywhere.

Note: This answer was added before the function clause was added.

Comment: Apologies. Forgot to mention a slightly complicating detail that they are local variables :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bad idea, but... well, if it is imperative...

It makes no sense to change a script in a `<script>` tag - if it is in DOM, it has already executed (and no longer matters). Thus, to change the script before it has a chance to execute, you need to load it using AJAX, change the text, then `eval` it.

Comment: Agreed that 99% of the time it's definitely an odd thing to do. I think there's a weird occasion here or there where it could be useful. I am re ```eval()```'ing it via the other script already so that it re-executes. Thanks though :-)